# What is the correct way to work with an .mdf database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've had quite a bit of difficulty with this.  I want to create a database and a table underneath, which I assume I just use the Data Sources and Add New Data Source.

But then things get crazy.  I want to have a data set in memory, so I drag the Table to the Windows form, which creates a DataGridView and a navigation bar.

But I don't need any of that crap. And I don't want to bind directly to a particular control such as a Text box.  What if I just want to say, press a button, and have the program load data from a file and write it to the Database?  Should be straightforward right?

Well, that brings me to the next issue - when I see the database (.MDF) file in my Solution, In Properties I have the choices Copy Always, Copy if Newer, and Never copy.

Tried all three.  Copy always always seems to overwrite the changes?  Copy it newer seems to do the same thing.  And if I say Copy Never I get an error about a database with that name already existing?  What even good is "Copy Always"???  " Why yes. All those changes I made while running my application In would like to all disappear so I can't test it."

What is the correct way to do this stuff?  This is just nuts that I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: The **best way** is to stop fiddling around with `.mdf` files as such - put the database **on the server** (where it belongs) and let SQL Server handle all the details about file handling. Just create the database **on the server**, connect to the server using server/instance name and database name - that's all there is!

Answer (score 2):

The **best way** is to **stop fiddling** around with free-floating `.mdf` files altogether.

Put the database **on the server** (where it belongs) and let SQL Server handle all the details about file handling.

Just create the database **on the server**, connect to the server using server/instance name and database name

```
server=myhonker\SQL2012;database=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

that's all there is! No more messing around with copying files around, inserting into the wrong file and so forth....